# Container run can't be pinged from another container up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 4 containers ( A,B,C,D ) that i want to run with a docker-compose.yml file

They are all using the same custom network `intranet`

```
  intranet:
    driver: bridge
```

my container A is using

```
depends_on: 
  - B
  - C
  - D
```

to launch everything at once.

I do `docker-compose run A` and then i use a `docker-compose exec` to enter the container B.

From the container B i can `ping C` and `ping D` but when i `ping A` i get

```
XXX@XXX:/$ ping A
    ping: A: No address associated with hostname
```

The only way i can ping A is to do `docker ps`, fetch the container running name and use it : `ping projectname_A_run_1`.

Is there a way to ping the container A from container B with just a `ping A` ?

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  A:
    image: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY_DOMAIN}/${DOCKER_BUILD_TAG_A}"
    hostname: "A"
    ports:
      - "${LISTEN:-3001}:3000"
    tty: true
    environment:
      - DEBUG
      - DOCKER_COMPOSE=1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER
      - NODE_VERSION
      - NVM_DIR
      - PROJECT_NAME=A
      - QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
      - RAILS_ENV
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
      - SHELL=/bin/bash
    user: "${DOCKER_USER}"
    working_dir: "${A_WORKING_DIR}"
    volumes:
      - "./tmp/capybara:/tmp/capybara:rw"
    networks:
      - intranet
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
      - B
    entrypoint: "${A_ENTRYPOINT}"
  B:
    image: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY_DOMAIN}/${DOCKER_BUILD_TAG_B}"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
      - SETFCAP
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
      - seccomp:unconfined
    hostname: "B"
    environment:
      - DEBUG
      - DOCKER_COMPOSE=1
      - PROJECT_NAME=B
      - REDIS_HOST=localhost
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - SHELL=/bin/bash
    user: "${DOCKER_USER}"
    working_dir: "${B_WORKING_DIR}"
    networks:
      - intranet
    depends_on:
      - redis
    entrypoint: "${B_ENTRYPOINT}"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
    networks:
      - intranet
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "${LISTEN:-6379}:6379"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - intranet
networks:
  intranet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can we see what your `docker-compose.yml` looks like ?

Comment: I edited the original post with the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Can you show the contents of `/etc/hosts` from container B as well as the output of `docker ps` on the host?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

Use `docker-compose run --name A A`

The container that is run is gonna be reachable with its name